# Meta Box on Custom Post Type not saving

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have a custom post type which is working fine, however the meta box does isn't saving.

Long & short, i'm stumped!

```
add_action('init', 'portfolio');
function portfolio() {
 $args = array(
  'label' => __('Portfolio'),
  'singular_label' => __('Portfolio'),
  'public' => true,
  'show_ui' => true,
  'menu_position' => 5,
  'capability_type' => 'page',
  'hierarchical' => false,
  'rewrite' => true,
  'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
  'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
  'has_archive' => true
 );

 register_taxonomy( 'type', 'portfolio',
  array(
             'hierarchical' => false,
    'label' => __('Project Type'),
    'query_var' => 'type',
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio/type' )
  )
 );

 register_post_type( 'portfolio' , $args );
}

add_action("admin_init", "admin_init");
add_action('save_post', 'save_meta_data');

function admin_init(){
add_meta_box("portfolio_text", "Main Text", "portfolio_options", "portfolio", "normal", "high");
}

/* Meta Values for Shorts */
function portfolio_options() {
 global $post;
 $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
 $short_embed = $custom["portfolio_text"][0]; ?>
 <textarea name="portfolio_text" cols="40" rows="1" style="width:98%; height:100px"/><?php echo get_option('portfolio_text'); ?></textarea> 
<?php }


/* Save Changes */
function save_meta_data($ID = false, $post = false) {
    if($post->post_type != 'portfolio')
        return;
    update_post_meta($ID, 'portfolio_text', $_POST['portfolio_text']);
}
```

Your help is appreciated!

Cheers,
George

Comment: Paste your save_meta_data function so we can see

Comment: do you mean, function save_meta_data($ID = false, $post = false) {
    if($post->post_type != 'portfolio')
        return;
    update_post_meta($ID, 'portfolio_text', $_POST['portfolio_text']);
}

Comment: I mean the function that acutely saves the meta data, that could it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@George Wiscombe:**

So close, yet so far! *(I know the pain, I'm there often. :)*  You almost had it but are using the wrong hook to do the post meta update.  Use the `'wp_insert_post_data'` hook instead of the `'save_post'` hook:

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('YourSite_Portfolio')) {
  class YourSite_Portfolio {
    static function on_load() {
      add_action('init',array(__CLASS__,'init'));
      add_action("admin_init",array(__CLASS__,'admin_init'));
      add_action('wp_insert_post_data',array(__CLASS__,'wp_insert_post_data'),10,2);
    }
    static function init() {
      register_post_type( 'portfolio',array(
        'label' => __('Portfolio'),
        'singular_label' => __('Portfolio'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'capability_type' => 'page',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'has_archive' => true
      ));
      register_taxonomy( 'type', 'portfolio', array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'label' => __('Project Type'),
        'query_var' => 'type',
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio/type' )
      ));
    }
    static function admin_init(){
      add_meta_box('portfolio_text','Main Text',array(__CLASS__,'portfolio_options'),'portfolio','normal','high');
    }
    static function portfolio_options($post,$metabox) {
      $portfolio_text =  get_post_meta($post->ID,'portfolio_text',true);
    $html =<<<HTML
<textarea name="portfolio_text" cols="40" rows="1" style="width:98%; height:100px"/>{$portfolio_text}</textarea>
HTML;
      echo $html;
    }
    static function wp_insert_post_data($data,$postarr) {
      if ($postarr['post_type'] == 'portfolio') {
        update_post_meta($postarr['ID'], 'portfolio_text', $postarr['portfolio_text']);
      }
      return $data;
    }
  }
  YourSite_Portfolio::on_load();
}
```

The `'wp_insert_post_data'` hook is where WordPress captures the values from the `$_POST` array; by the time you reach `'save_post'` WordPress has reloaded the post and that's why `'portfolio_text'` empty when you are trying to save it.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for your feedback. I swapped out my save action/function for yours however I'm still getting the same problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @George Wiscombe - I was clearly brainfried when I posted that, sorry. I've updated it and I've rewritten it to use a class to encapsulate everything to minimize the likelihood of it conflicting with a *(badly written)* plugin you might use. Since you were using function names like `admin_init()` and `save_meta_data()` in the global function namespace it's likely those would conflict with someone else's plugin code *(or even future code from WordPress)* so what I've done pretty much eliminates that concern.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Mike! This is perfect. If you have another couple of minutes, could you show me an example that would have 2+ custom fields. (I'm just trying to understand it as opposed to copy&paste)

Comment: @George Wiscombe - Glad I could help. Just add fields in your `portfolio_options()` and `wp_insert_post_data()` functions. Very straightforward.

Comment: Great thanks, actually after a bit more testing i've found a problem. It now doesn't save the content of the default WP text-area, any ideas?

Comment: @George Wiscombe - Sorry, it was an unfortunate yet simple bug on my part. Add `return $data;` to the `wp_insert_post_data()` function *(I've updated the code in my answer to be correct.)*

Answer (score 4):

the problem is with your portfolio_options function in this line:

```
<textarea name="portfolio_text" cols="40" rows="1" style="width:98%; height:100px"/><?php echo get_option('portfolio_text');** ?></textarea>
```

its being saved and have been before but you are not calling it the right way, you are using 
**get_option**('portfolio_text') and that's not right because it not an option is a post metadata

so change get_option('portfolio_text') to get_post_meta($post->ID, 'portfolio_text', true);

so your function will look like this:

```
/* Meta Values for Shorts */
function portfolio_options() {
 global $post;
 $custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);
 $short_embed = $custom["portfolio_text"][0]; ?>
 <textarea name="portfolio_text" cols="40" rows="1" style="width:98%; height:100px"/><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'portfolio_text', true); ?></textarea> 
<?php }
```

that should do it!

Comment: @בניית אתרי - Good catch on the `get_option()`; I missed that part when eyeballing it. +1.